# i want to get ride of the index that gets printed

Tags: python

```
year():
    print("Type '2018' to select the data of 2018")
    print("Type '2019' to select the data of 2019")
    print("Type '2020' to select the data of 2020")
    print("Type '0' to close selection")

    ,,, def data_frame():
        while True:
            year()
            a=int(input("Select the year:"))
            if a == 2018:
                csv = pd.read_csv("C:\\\\Users\\\\seena\\\\OneDrive\\\\Desktop\\\\2022-11-18 20.55.00\\\\Project csv BOTH.csv")#importing a csv file
                df1=pd.DataFrame(csv)
                print(df1)
            elif a == 0:
                break
            else :
                print("Invalid choice")
            c = input("Press Enter to continue selection") ,,,
```

i tryed making index as false but its not working for me i also cant seem to find a better way

what i get is :

```
select the year :2020
output:
0 1 203 283
1 2 376 249
```

what i want is to get rid of the index or replace it with the month is all

Comment: How about `index=False`?

Comment: @buduker i tryed the index =  false its not working for some reason cant find out why but ty anyway and it was helpfull the link ty

Answer (score -1):

Try index_col="month"

Comment: hey ty for the reply but it didnt work i found one that did though so ty anyway